# Max of two Columns, within found set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a large activity pull where I have to get the last activity of selected ca.matter_key's in a table, determined by ca.activity_key (tables primary key). I would like to know the most efficient way of getting this as the end result will be in the ballpark of 20K.

```
    select distinct

    ca.matter_key,
    ca.activity_key,
    ca.actrow1,
    ca.actrow2,
    ca.actrow3,
    ca.actrow4

    FROM CaseAct ca

    where
    ca.matter_key in (
    4945046,
    5040953,
    5025296,
    5078360
    )
```

The result from above will give the below result:

```
Matter_key  activity_key actrow1 actrow2 actrow3 actrow4
4945046     12           Data    Data    Data    Data    
4945046     13           Data    Data    Data    Data    
4945046     14           Data    Data    Data    Data    
5040953     35           Data    Data    Data    Data    
5040953     36           Data    Data    Data    Data    
5025296     77           Data    Data    Data    Data    
5025296     78           Data    Data    Data    Data    
5025296     79           Data    Data    Data    Data    
5078360     NULL         Data    Data    Data    Data     
4887024     93           Data    Data    Data    Data    
4887024     94           Data    Data    Data    Data    
4887024     95           Data    Data    Data    Data    
5061591     NULL         Data    Data    Data    Data
```

And I need:

```
Matter_key  activity_key actrow1 actrow2 actrow3 actrow4 
4945046     14           Data    Data    Data    Data    
5040953     36           Data    Data    Data    Data      
5025296     79           Data    Data    Data    Data    
5078360     NULL         Data    Data    Data    Data    
4887024     95           Data    Data    Data    Data    
5061591     NULL         Data    Data    Data    Data
```

I've done this on previous sets using a combination of group by ca.matter_key, and Max(ca.activity_key) using criteria, however I need the pre-selected matter_keys, which is a large list. Also, is Where in ca.activity_key() the most efficient way of pulling this list?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where did `Matter_key`s `4887024` and `5061591` come from...?  Your query is already filtering on the `Matter_key` column, and those are not in the query.

Comment: apologies, I was manually deleting rows for readability, they must have been swept up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select ca.*
from (select ca.*,
             row_number() over (partition by matter_key order by activity_key desc) as seqnum
      from CaseAct ca
      where ca.matter_key in (4945046, 5040953, 5025296, 5078360)
     ) ca
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Question before I run: why select CA.*  and not  ca.matter_key, ca.activity_key, ca.actrow1,..? I ask because it's a very wide (and largely inefficient) DB.

Comment: if you are selecting all  columns from Ca as shown in your question,it doesnt matter

Comment: Ah, I see. Apologies, I only gave a select amount of columns in the example, as I figure they weren't the focus of the question. The actual select query is around 20 cols, and the table is around 120 (as before,an extremely inefficient table!)

Comment: @rattacat . . . I just shortened the `select` because it is irrelevant to the real question and is easier to type.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use below

```
select 
    ca.matter_key,
    ca.activity_key,
    ca.actrow1,
    ca.actrow2,
    ca.actrow3,
    ca.actrow4
    FROM CaseAct ca 
join
(
select matter_key,max(activity_key) as maxkey 
from
caseact ) b
on b.matter_key=ca.matter_key
  and b.maxkey=a.activity_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something here but surely it's as simple as this:

```
select ca.matter_key,
       max(ca.activity_key) activity_key,
       ca.actrow1,
       ca.actrow2,
       ca.actrow3,
       ca.actrow4
from CaseAct ca
where ca.matter_key in (4945046,
                        5040953,
                        5025296,
                        5078360)
group by ca.matter_key,
         ca.actrow1,
         ca.actrow2,
         ca.actrow3,
         ca.actrow4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
a.matter_key,
a.activity_key,
a.actrow1,
a.actrow2,
a.actrow3,
a.actrow4
FROM yourtable a
join
(
select matter_key, max(isnull(activity_key, 0)) as maxi 
from yourtable ) b
on b.matter_key=a.matter_key
and b.maxi =isnull(a.activity_key, 0)
```